# Manipulating a list and then passing it as an optional argument

Tags: latex3, token-lists

I want to remove one key given by `#1` and then pass the modified list to `\lstinline[<modified list>]$#2$`. I am able to remove the element but don't know the syntax of passing the rest to `\lstinline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_target_tl
\clist_new:N \l__aljumaily_elements_tl
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\inline}{O{}m}{
  \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_target_tl{language=java}
    \clist_clear:N \l__aljumaily_elements_tl
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__aljumaily_elements_tl {#1}
    
    Before~removal:~\l__aljumaily_elements_tl\newline\newline
    \clist_remove_all:NV \l__aljumaily_elements_tl \l__aljumaily_target_tl

    After~removal:~\l__aljumaily_elements_tl\newline
    \lstinline[\l__aljumaily_elements_tl]$#2$ % not working!
\group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
  \inline[language=java, basicstyle=\ttfamily, showspaces, emph={public}]{public void x() \{ ... \}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few hints before starting:

1. a `clist` variable should be named `..._clist`, not `_tl`;
2. the command you're trying to define is not expandable;
3. `\clist_set:Nn` is easier than clearing the variable and then doing `\clist_put_right:Nn`

Now the issue: when `\lstinline` reads its optional argument, it doesn't expand it. You can do it before calling `\lstinline`.

(Not that I'm understanding what you're trying to do.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_target_tl
\clist_new:N \l__aljumaily_elements_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aljumaily_lstinline:n
  {
    \lstinline[#1]
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__aljumaily_lstinline:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand{\inline}{O{}m}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_target_tl {language=java}
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__aljumaily_elements_clist {#1}
    \clist_remove_all:NV \l__aljumaily_elements_clist \l__aljumaily_target_tl
    \__aljumaily_lstinline:e { \clist_use:Nn \l__aljumaily_elements_clist { , } } $#2$
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lstinline[language=java, basicstyle=\ttfamily, showspaces, emph={public}]$public void x() \{ ... \}$

\inline[language=java, basicstyle=\ttfamily, showspaces, emph={public}]{public void x() \{ ... \}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should explain the need of `\cs_generate_variant`.